# What is difference between fog computing and local computing

Tags: fog-computing

I read this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08997.pdf

In the paper,it said

Let "D_i" denote the computation tasks data size of the i-th EH device and O_i be the part for fog computing. Thus, the rest data with size of (D_i − O_i ) is
for local computing.

it mentions about the fog computing and local computing,i know what is fog computing ,fog computing is like a little cloud computing,but the fog computing can be embedded into smart-phone,air-condition,etc,fog computing can help us calculate something,store something ,so it can be apply to the IoT,,but i don't know what is the local computing,what does it do?does anyone know about that

Comment: "local computing" sounds to me like no internet connection, but that's just a guess

Comment: so local computing like the device does the information decoding for itself,and fog computing will transmit the information ,so the other device can harvest the RF signal at the same time?

Comment: That would be my ***guess***, but you probably ought to ask whoever coined, or uses, the term, what they m,mean by it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this question was lost in the fog. Took me 4 years to see it !
For those that come by, here's my take on it.
Local computing happens within a device. The cloud computing happens far away, in a data center, usually requiring going on the internet to reach the cloud computing infrastructure.
A fog is like a mini cloud, near the device. Usually available via Wifi/LAN from the device in question. The main purposes of a fog are one/more among:

- Reduce device size/power needs by offloading complex computing.
- Filtering of data
- Buffering of data

In the paper that is linked, they are talking mostly about reducing device power by offloading computing to the fog.
Now, if you ever want to look at the difference between edge computing and fog computing, the answer is a bit foggy. Have you ever tried to find the edge of a fog ? In my mind, there are not many use cases for having both, especially considering maintenance of infrastructure for both fog and edge.